# Add a line of code in multiple php file

Tags: php

I have more than hundreds of php file with the different codes and i want to add a few line of code in all of our php file, for example we have   `1.php, 2.php, 3.php and so on...` files and i want to add a php include function

```
<?php 'include common.php'; ?>
```

to all of my php file, I can also add this code manually to all of my php file but, it will take to much time. So How can i do this ? I am using windows operating system so plz help us.

Comment: Does that page have something that they already include? like a db connection file? if yes you can add it inside the included file

Comment: Well, write a program that does it for you. You can use PHP for simple scripting operations, too. Oh, and make backups! However, also check the PHP commandline options, you can tell PHP to prepend another file before the regular one, as a separate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bash script like the following one (assuming you don't have white spaces in your paths)

```
for file in $(find . -name "*php"); do
  echo "<?php 'include common.php'; ?>" > temp.txt
  cp $file $file.bakcup
  cat $file >> temp.txt
  mv temp.txt $file
done
```